# After redirection from the server, a 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' error is encountered in Next 14

Tags: node.js, next.js, cors, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I'm using Next.js 14 with Express and attempting to implement Google OAuth using `passport-google-oauth2`. However, I'm encountering an error on my frontend. When my server sends a redirection link to the frontend, I encounter a CORS error. My backend is functioning correctly because when I copy that link and paste it into a new tab, everything works fine.

Here is my code where I'm making a GET request to my server:

```js
const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
  startTransition(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.get("/api/auth/google", {
        withCredentials: true,
      });

      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
};
```

And here is the Passport.js implementation and CORS config:

```js
app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3001/api/auth/callback/google",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

app.get(
  "/api/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["email", "profile"],
    session: false,
  })
);

app.get(
  "/api/auth/callback/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    session: false,
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  }
);

// CORS
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

The error I am encountering is:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fgoogle&scope=email%20profile&client_id=CLIENT_ID. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

Could anyone help me fix this error?